Can I use Shared Element Transition Animation in a Compose with Fragment Navigation
I am currently working on an Android project where I have implemented a FragmentA and a BottomSheetFragmnetB using Jetpack Compose. Both of these fragments utilize traditional Fragment Navigation rather than the newer Compose Navigation.
I am aware that there are two main approaches for implementing shared element transitions:
Using Views and Fragment Navigation
Using Compose with Compose Navigation
However, in my case, I need to implement shared element transitions between my Compose-based fragments while continuing to use Fragment Navigation.
Is it possible to achieve shared element transitions with Compose fragments under these circumstances? If so, could you provide guidance or examples on how to implement this?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Simple answer is we cant do shared transition between XML and Compose.
We can do instead is convert one of them to XML or Compose and bring it to single logic then perform what ever we want.
Compose is really easy for migration, so give it a try.
Hope this helps

Thanks for answer. Project is big, migration would take time. I think there should be some workarounds :'(
